# java: implementing binary search tree and overriding iterable

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

I want to be able to use a for each loop but i end up in an infinite loop.
I'm not using recursion and the debugger is not giving me any hints. If it is, I'm not getting it.
Here's my tester:

```
    Student stud1 = new Student("nic", "aichael", "1234", 75, 90);
    Student stud2 = new Student("nic", "bichael", "1234", 75, 90);
    Student stud3 = new Student("nic", "cichael", "1234", 75, 90);
    Student stud4 = new Student("nic", "dichael", "1234", 75, 90);
    AVLPersonTree tree = new AVLPersonTree();
    tree.add(stud1);
    tree.add(stud2);
    tree.add(stud3);
    tree.add(stud4);
    for(Node node: tree){
        node.toString();
     }
```

Here is my AVLPersonTree class:

```
    public class AVLPersonTree implements Iterable<Node>{
private Node root;
private int size;

public AVLPersonTree(){
    super();
    root = null;
}

public void add(Person newPerson){
    Node newNode = new Node(newPerson);
    if(root == null){
        root = newNode;
    }else{
        root.addNode(newNode);
    }
    size++;
}

public int size(){
    return size;
}


@Override
public Iterator iterator() {
    Iterator<Node> iterate = new Iterator(){

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if(root == null){
                return false;
            }
            if(root.getLeftNode() == null && root.getRightNode() == null){
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Node next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException("no more elements");
            }
            return preorderNext();
            }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

    };
    return iterate;
}

private Node preorderNext() {
    Stack<Node> visiting = new Stack<>();
if (visiting.empty()) { // at beginning of iterator
    visiting.push(root);
}
Node node = visiting.pop();
// need to visit the left subtree first, then the right
// since a stack is a LIFO, push the right subtree first, then
// the left.  Only push non-null trees
if (node.getRightNode() != null) {
    visiting.push(node.getRightNode());
}
if (node.getLeftNode() != null) {
    visiting.push(node.getLeftNode());
}
// may not have pushed anything.  If so, we are at the end
if (visiting.empty()) { // no more nodes to visit
    root = null;
}
return node;
}
```

}

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: the for each loops indefinitely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "preorderNext" function is wrong.

The 5 line at the begening will always bring you the "root" in "node"

```
Stack<Node> visiting = new Stack<>();
if (visiting.empty()) { // at beginning of iterator
visiting.push(root);
}
Node node = visiting.pop();
```

so you never really iterating  , the node will be forever "root"